# Java compilation errors concerning SQLException and RemoteException

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm working on RMI and SQL programming using ubuntu 15.04. I'm coding the following 3 files: ServerIntf.java , ServerImpl.java, and Server.java

When I compile the ServerImpl file, I get following exceptions: SQLEXception and RemoteException.

How can I compile and execute server please?

**error:**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGF0P.png)

This is my code :

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerIntf {

    public ServerImpl() throws RemoteExeption{ }

    public Connection Connect () throws RemoteExeption{ 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/banque";
        String name = "root";
        String pass = "root";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,pass);
            return cn;
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String AddC(int cin , float solde) throws RemoteExeption{
        String res = " Ajout avec succse";  
        try{
            Connection cnx = Connect();
            PreparedStatement ins = cnx.preparedStatement("insert into clients values(?,?)");
        ins.setString(1,Integer.toString(cin));
        ins.setString(2,Float.toString(solde));
        ins.executeUpdate();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        return res;
    } 
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGF0P.png)

Comment: Instead of including screenshots of please copy the text into your question.

Comment: You are not getting exceptions. You are getting compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 typos in your code:

1. It is not `RemoteExeption` but `RemoteException` indeed a `c` is missing
2. It is not `preparedStatement` but `prepareStatement` indeed there is no `d`

Comment: Thank you for reponding, i fix the code , but the error still here, i changed the screenshot egain , u can take a lock if you want

Comment: @Malek Ben el ouafi Try using an IDE, that makes your live easier.

Comment: i fix the problem 
`Connection cnx = Connect();
   Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement();
   String sql = "insert into clients values('"+Integer.toString(cin)+"','"+Float.toString(solde)+"')";
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);`

Comment: oh no please keep PreparedStatement, it is much better than a simple Statement